# ArcPy not detecting colorizer when layer set to stretched symbology

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, symbology

ArcPy is not detecting a raster layer's "colorizer" type when the layer is set to "Stretch" symbology. The ESRI [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/rasterstretchcolorizer-class.htm) suggests this should be possible. Am I missing something?

Here is the Python snippet shown in the screenshot:

```
import arcpy
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('current')
for mp in p.listMaps('*'):
  print(f"Check '{mp.name}' map for raster layers, and their symbology")
  for l in mp.listLayers():
     if l.isRasterLayer:
         sym = l.symbology
         if hasattr(sym, 'colorizer'):
             print(f"\t {l.name} has a colorizer type of {sym.colorizer.type}")
         else:
             print(f"\t Unknown symbology for '{l.name}'")
```

[image: Two ArcPro screenshots with python snippet]